# Yii Relations not working

Tags: php, yii

hi i want to view customer's name using print_r(); here is my table structure:

```
Table Customers
  id
  name
Table Jobs
  id
  customer (REF of Customers table)
```

here is my code:

in my customer model:

```
return array(
            'name'=>array( self::HAS_MANY, 'Job', 'customer' ),
        );
```

in my Jobs Table

```
return array(
            'customer'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customers', 'customer'),
        );
```

in my JobsController:

```
reports=Jobs::model()->findAll();
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($reports);
            echo '</pre>';
```

the output is here:

```
Array
(
     [0] => JobsObject
        (
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [customer] => 1
this is my expectation:

Array
(
    [0] => JobsObject
        (
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
             [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [customer] => 1
```

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: Why there should be `name`? Did you add something to a query that defines getting `name` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reports=Jobs::model()->with('customer')->findAll();
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($reports);
            echo '</pre>';
```

as far i know you will not get inside job record...
you will get different object to fetch the data for respective user like

```
Array
(
    [0] => JobsObject
        (
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [customer] => 1
            [customersRecord] => Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Your aim (the second array you printed) is wrong, because you want to inject the name attribute that belongs to the Customers table inside the Jobs Object.
To read the data related you simply have to access this way (or something like that):

```
$this->job->customer
```

(customer is the name of the relation, $this->job is the current row/object you are reading)